# Collections sort method

Tags: java, sorting, collections

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-

> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the
>   specified comparator. All elements in the list must be mutually
>   comparable using the specified comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2)
>   must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the
>   list).

Why doesn't it specify whether objects are sorted in ascending or descending order? In the `Comparator` interface `compare` method tells when `obj1` is greater than equal to or less than `obj2`. That's it. The documentation doesn't say if the list is sorted in ascending order. I have checked it myself and yes, it is ascending.

Comment: Ascending or descending makes no sense. It sorts according to the comparator. So the comparator may sort ascendingly or descendingly, but that matter is up to the comparator. Not the sorting logic.

Comment: @Tunaki Comparator's compare method defines when objects are larger or smaller. The sort method sorts it in the ascending order, and it determines the meaning of ascending by looking at the comparator. But the documentation doesn't mention that the order is ascending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither "ascending order" or "descending order" makes sense here when you're dealing with a custom `Comparator`. The `Comparator` itself imposes some order, which may be "ascending" or "descending" in terms of the natural ordering of the objects, if such a natural ordering even exists. It would be *wrong* for the documentation for `sort` to say "ascending" because if you pass it a `Comparator` that imposes a descending ordering, the sort will be descending.

The error is in the [documentation for Comparator.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). It says "less than" and "greater than" when it really means "comes before" and "comes after".

A `Comparator` that defines a descending order won't fit with this particular aspect of the documentation, but that's simply a documentation issue. Most of the rest of the documentation for `Comparator` doesn't use this terminology and just correctly talks about orderings.

Answer (score 2):

The collection is sorted in **ascending** order, according to the given `Comparator` (or the natural ordering of the elements if they are `Comparable`s and a `Comparator` is not provided).

As to why the documentation doesn't explicitly state it - you'll have to ask the JDK's authors, but it's pretty common in English to assume that sorting implicitly means ascending order, and this convention carries over to software engineering quite often. E.g., in SQL, the `order by` clause implicitly assumes `ASC`, even if it's not explicitly stated.

Comment: If the comparator were imposing a e.g. a descending order on integers you wouldn't say it was "in ascending order" according to the comparator though, would you?

Comment: @CupawnTae I would, actually, but maybe that's splitting hairs. A `Comparator` defines an ordering where you could say that X is either before ("less than") Y, after it ("more than") or in the position ("equal to"). `Collections.sort` sorts a list according to this ordering. If it just happens to be a descending numeric order, so be it, `Collections.sort` doesn't care about it.

Comment: @CupawnTae but I guess it's a matter of how you look at it.

Comment: I would have said that "ascending" and "descending" are aspects of the natural ordering, rather than of the order imposed by the `Comparator`. So you can have a `Comparator` that imposes an ascending order, and another that imposes a descending order, and you can have the reverse order of a `Comparator`, but saying "ascending order according to a descending `Comparator`" would be a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

The sort order will be determined by the implementation of `Comparator` or `Comparable` so the `Collections.sort` method cannot guarantee ascending or descending order.